# visualize n-triple file python

Tags: python-3.x, sparql, rdf, rdflib, sparqlwrapper

Is there a module or tool in Python that will help me visualize RDF data?
I have a N-Triple file and want to load it in python and display the information in it visually. I am currently using RDFLib but it does not have a visualize function. Thank you.

Comment: visualize as what? graph? you can use any graph API in Python then...just have to write a convert from RDF triples to a graph which is trivial. that said, asking for a tools etc. is not recommended on StackOverflow...

Comment: What graph API in python? I did not know about those... I just want to visualize it as a graph.

The way I found was to convert my N-Triples file into a json file using:
http://rdf-translator.appspot.com/
Afterwards, I input the json-ld file content on this web to generate the visual graph:
https://json-ld.org/playground/

Comment: I mean any visualization tool that can process graphs resp. networks. there must be dozens of those out there

Comment: "graph? you can use any graph API in Python then..." Are you referring to tools like matplolib? I want to know where to look at.

"just have to write a convert from RDF triples to a graph which is trivial." Please explain how to would do that in detail, I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Sorry I meant graphviz not matplotlib...

Comment: With trivial I mean, that any RDF triple is just an edge between two nodes. That is trivial to take an arbitrary graph API in Python (please use google, there are dozens) and add those edges to the graph - or not?

Answer (score 1):

The way I found was to convert my N-Triples file into a json file using (under input field - copied my entire n-triple file and pasted it there): http://rdf-translator.appspot.com/

Afterwards, I input the json-ld file content on this web to generate the visual graph: https://json-ld.org/playground/ -> Go at the bottom of the page and clicked on the `Visualized` button.

[how the graph looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hULy9.png)

Comment: Well, do you really like this visualization? To be honest, I find it neither fancy nor comfortable. No layout options, no zooming, no panning, etc. and it will never scale to a larger RDF graphs ...

Answer (score 0):

Consider this tool I found very useful and user-friendly:
[Ontology Visualization](https://github.com/fatestigma/ontology-visualization)